# Laravel Throttle Middleware: is there a callback / handler for it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, throttling

I want to use [Laravel's Throttle Middleware](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php#L77), but I want to also log any cases where the user made too many attempts.

Is there any Callback / Handler where I can detect this and do something with it?

Let's say I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('foo', array('before' => 'throttle:5,10', function () {
    return 'You shall pass!';
}, ));
```

Answer (score 2):

If it reaches the max count, it will fire this event:

```
Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout
```

So you can probably listen to it

```
protected $listen = [
    ...
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogLockout',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Sounds great but I can't see that it triggers the event when RateLimit is reached. I am also looking at the class and I don't see where it fires an event https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php

Answer (score 2):

`Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout` event is only fired in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins` but you can still fire it by hand.

This is how I've done that:

1. In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` add these `use` statements:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
```

2. Add this to `report` method of the same file:

```php
if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
    if ('Too Many Attempts.' == $exception->getMessage()) {
        event(new Lockout(request()));
    }
}
```

3. Execute `php artisan make:listener LogThrottleLimitReached` and add this code inside `handle` method of `app/Listeners/LogThrottleLimitReached.php` file:

```php
$request = $event->request;

\Log::error(sprintf(
    'Throttling rate limit reached. URL: %s, Body: %s, IP: %s',
    $request->url(),
    json_encode($request->all()),
    $request->ip()
));
```

4. Register that listener in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

```php
use App\Listeners\LogThrottleLimitReached;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
```

and

```php
protected $listen = [
    Lockout::class => [
        LogThrottleLimitReached::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! The only thing I changed was to check inside the Handler class, if the exception is of type `ThrottleRequestsException` instead of `HttpException` and then comparing `429 === $exception->getStatusCode()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just extend the `ThrottleRequests` class and redeclare its `buildException`, or try handling its exception (`\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` with 429 'Too Many Attempts.') inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.